# 1TB hard drive not working on RedHat linux workstation, dialouge box saying ntfs is not installed on your system comes

Tags: linux, ntfs

I have this new 1TB hard-drive from Sandisk for the purpose of taking backup from my linux (Redhat) based linux system, but when i try to use it, a dialouge box comes saying that u do not have NTFS system installed on your system. Please help how can i make use of this hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to format it in something linux can understand. So, if there's no data on it, try this, after doing some substitution:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdX1
```

change X with the correct device

Answer (score 1):

Your options are to reformat the drive or to install ntfs-3g on the system.

To reformat the drive, type this:

> sudo mkfs.ext2 *partition* (partition is probably /dev/sda1 or /dev/sdb1)

I'm not quite sure how to install ntfs-3g on Redhat. I just searched my yum repos and it doesn't look like it's offered. You'll have to find another repo, download the rpm somewhere, or build it from source.

It's much better just to use a native filesystem though. So my recommendation is to reformat the drive.

Comment: Why just ext2? That's getting a bit long in the tooth at this stage! Typo I presume?